# Create image from ESRI VectorTileServer using script

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, vector-tiles

I have service from ESRI VectorTileServer

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/Esri_Childrens_Map/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf
```

Map example:

```
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/Esri_Childrens_Map/VectorTileServer?f=jsapi
```

There is possible create print image (jpg or png) for specified bbox coordinates and zoom level (scale)? What tools can I use for creating this images?

For creating images from ESRI VectorTileServer I finded this example:

```
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=widgets-print-vectortiles
```

but there is not available call print using for example python script.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this
One day just export.from ArcGIS arcmap or ArcGIS pro

Second way 
Download PBF for area of interests zoom column row
Package as MBTILES with [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) 
Fire up Docker [tileserver-gl](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl)
ADD your mbtiles and json style
Request tiles as PNG

ASSEMBLE tiles into one image via [untiler](https://github.com/mapbox/untiler) or generate MBTILES and use [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to output to other format like tif

Comment: can you please explain how to export raster image from ESRI VectorTileServer using ArcGIS ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro. Thanks!